# How to prevent dividing options tags elements into two parts on IE?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've got one problem with my select element and it's only appear on IE. Each time when i click on it i got separated options elements (one half goes above and second goes down). I don't know why it's happening, i just want all my options element to go under select tag.
So, my select tag is pretty much an ordinary tag:

[image]

and when i click i got this:

[image]

It's really annoying stuff...

Any suggestion?

Comment: The menu items are always in the order that the options appear. If the selected item is in the middle, that's where it will appear when the menu opens.

Comment: ahh, yeah, i get it now... thank you so much